# How can I display pictures from the database into heredoc?

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to display Images into the heredoc it can’t work and I get no errors 
But if I display  them out if the heredoc they displayed nicely . what might be the problem?
For any help I will appreciate it .
Here is the code and I did display the Images twice , in heredoc and out so that u get a clear view .

```
<?Php
$target = "image_uploads/";
$image_name = (isset($_POST['image_name']));
$query ="select * from
 tish_user inner join tish_images
 on tish_user.user_id = tish_images.user_id
 WHERE tish_images.prof_image = 1";
    $result= $con->prepare($query);
    $result->execute();

$table = <<<ENDHTML
<div style ="text-align:center;">
<h2>Client Review Software</h2>
<table id ="heredoc" border ="0" cellpaddinig="2" cellspacing="2" style = "width:100%" ;
margin-left:auto; margin-right: auto;>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Ref No</th>
<th>Cell</th>
<th>Picture</th>
</tr>
ENDHTML;

while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $date_created = $row['date_created'];
        $user_id = $row['user_id'];
        $username = $row['username'];

        $image_id = $row['image_id'];
        #this is the Tannery  operator to replace a pic when an id do not have one
$photo = ($row['image_name']== null)? "me.png":$row['image_name'];
#display image 
             # I removed this line up to here 
        echo '<img src="'.$target.$photo.'" width="100" height="100">';



$table .=  <<<ENDINFO
<tr>
<td><a href ="client_details.php?user_id=$user_id">$username </a></td>
<td>$image_id</td>
<td></td>
<td>c</td>
<td><img src="'.$target.$photo.'" width="100" height="100">
</td>
</tr>
ENDINFO;
}
    $table .= <<<ENDHTML
</table>
<p>$numrows"Clients</p>
</div>
ENDHTML;
echo $table;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td><img src="'.$target.$photo.'" width="100" height="100">
```

This line in your heredoc doesn't make sense to me. You should directly use the variables within the string, without the single-quotes and the concatentation-dots.

Like this:

```
<td><img src="$target$photo" width="100" height="100">
```

But because you want two variables printed right after each other, you probably need to use the curly syntax:

```
<td><img src="{$target}{$photo}" width="100" height="100">
```

You can read more about the curly syntax 
[here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing). You basically wrap the variables in curly braces (`{` and `}`) to help PHP understand where your variable names start and end.

Answer (score 2):

use `heredoc` and in the browser where image is not displayed check its source

the image src would be like this `<img src="'.../images/.me.png.'" ...` which is wrong as you can see the single quote and extra . (period sign) inside the double quote for img src

try this code

```
$table .=  <<<ENDINFO
<tr>
<td><a href ="client_details.php?user_id=$user_id">$username </a></td>
<td>$image_id</td>
<td></td>
<td>c</td>
<td><img src="{$target}{$photo}" width="100" height="100">
</td>
</tr>
ENDINFO;
}
```

so

```
<img src="'.$target.$photo.'" width="100" height="100">
```

will be

```
<img src="{$target}{$photo}" width="100" height="100">
```

let me know if this solves, please always do check HTML Source from browser's `view source` option to see what got printed

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this and display the declared variable anywhere you want.
also delete this  inside the heredoc  there put $pic.

```
$pic = '<img src="'.$target.$photo.'" width="50" height="50">';
 echo $pic  ;
```

Comment: ok I did use this and worked but I do not know is its the best or not